Create Dict in Python from excel data
I want to create a dictionary from the values from excel cells. For example, the table is below:



Column 1
Column 2
Column C3




a
b
c


d
e
f



and I want to create a dictionary, like below, that consists of the values coming from the excel cells
{'a' : ('b', 'c'), 'd' : ('e', 'f')}

I tried using pandas as described in my code below.
path_sheet = 'path_sheet_name.xls'
df = read_excel(path_sheet, header=[0], index_col=[1,2])
my_dic = df.to_dict()
print(my_dic)

However, it is returning:
{'Column 1': {('b', 'c') : 'a', ('e', 'f') : 'd'}}

I am having a hard time to modify this. Any idea on how I can create this dictionary?

I'm surprised that df.to_dict() returns {('b', 'c') : 'a', ('e', 'f') : 'd'}. It should return a nested dictionary ({'Column 1': {('b ', 'c'): 'a ', ('e ', 'f'): 'd '}}).

ideed, I forgot to add the {'Column 1':

OK, then you need to set the first column as index, transpose, and use to_dict('list') (see below).

Since you want the first column to be the key of your dictionary, you must set this one as index, not [1, 2]. You also most likely need to transpose and use to_dict('list')
df = read_excel(path_sheet, header=[0], index_col=0)
my_dic = df.T.to_dict('list')

Output:
{'a' : ['b', 'c'], 'd' : ['e', 'f']}

For tuples:
df = read_excel(path_sheet, header=[0], index_col=0)
my_dict = df.agg(tuple, axis=1).to_dict()

Output:
{'a ': ('b ', 'c'), 'd ': ('e ', 'f')}

